# Constraint on MySql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MySql table:

| domain | cardId | default |
| --- | --- | --- |
| google.com | 45 | 0 |
| google.com | 46 | 0 |
| google.com | 47 | 1 |

Is it possible to have a constraint on this table such that for every unique domain, there must be at least one row with default 1?

So the next insert would fail:

| domain | cardId | default |
| --- | --- | --- |
| google.com | 45 | 0 |
| google.com | 46 | 0 |
| google.com | 47 | 1 |
| facebook.com | 56 | 0 |

But this would work:

| domain | cardId | default |
| --- | --- | --- |
| google.com | 45 | 0 |
| google.com | 46 | 0 |
| google.com | 47 | 1 |
| facebook.com | 56 | 1 |
| facebook.com | 56 | 0 |

Comment: I don't think so. `CHECK` constraints can't execute subqueries.

Comment: Maybe you can do it using a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

Comment: @Bamar - Re: `BEFORE INSERT` won't stop deleting default record at some point or changing it to non-default value.